# visual studio 2010 c# class and method list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm looking for a simple way to produce a full class list (along with their methods and fields) for a C# project I'm working on in VS2010. I have found that Doxygen is a useful tool for this, but I feel as though there should be a similar feature built into VS2010.

Thanks,

PM

EDIT: While the object browser is very useful, I can't find a way for it to directly produce a list ready for printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Class View or Object Browser.  (both are in the View menu)

Answer (score 1):

> While the object browser is very
>   useful, I can't find a way for it to
>   directly produce a list ready for
>   printing

Hard to tell, since you haven't mentioned in what context you need to retrieve the class list. If you're working on a VS package/plug-in then you can use the same set of APIs the VS-Shell uses. Check the VS extensibility docs on MSDN. The APIs are exposed in any .NET language, in C++, many can be used from simple VB-scripts. If you don't want to (or can't) use the VS SDK, then System.Reflection is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use the [PowerToys](http://modeling.codeplex.com/) addin to export the class members from a class diagram to XML